# Can't convert from int to char error c#

Tags: c#

I have this exercise. I don't know what the problem is, but I keep getting the error - can someone help me what is wrong please?

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
>   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
>   at exercise_4.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Courses\c#\beginner\visual studio\section 6 exercises\exercise 4\exercise 4\Program.cs:line 20

This is what is written in my console

Write a program and ask the user to supply a list of comma separated numbers (e.g 5, 1, 9, 2, 10). If the list is empty or includes less than 5 numbers, display "Invalid List" and ask the user to re-try; otherwise, display the 3 smallest numbers in the list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace exercise_4
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      while (true)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("write numbers seperated with coma");
        var numbers = new List<int>();
        var input = (Console.ReadLine());
        var value = input.Split(',');
        var conv =Convert.ToInt32(value);
        numbers.Add(conv);

        if (value.Length < 5)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("invalid list!! retry");
          continue;
        }
        else
        {
          numbers.Sort();
          Console.WriteLine(numbers[0] , numbers[1], numbers [2]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Split will return array. You cannot convert array to num . You may need to itrate and convert each numer into int.

Comment: Split returns an array of strings, i.e. value is an array is an array of strings. ToInt32 here expects a string (or in general any type implementing the IConvertible interface), which can't work. You need to loop through value, convert each single entry and add this to your numbers list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split method returns an array of strings. The exception is thrown because the following statement tries to cast the string[] to int:

```
 var conv =Convert.ToInt32(value);
```

You should iterate and parse each item in the array as follows:

```
while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("write numbers seperated with coma");
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            var input = (Console.ReadLine());
            var values = input.Split(',');

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                int number;

                // If the input can be parsed to int, add it to numbers list.
                if (int.TryParse(value, out number))
                {
                    numbers.Add(number);
                }
            }

            if (numbers.Count < 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("invalid list!! retry");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                numbers.Sort();
                numbers.Take(3)
                       .ToList()
                       .ForEach(number => Console.WriteLine(number));
            }
        }
```

Comment: so if i understand correctly: method  int.TryParse converts value from string to int ? and than actually the same i got logic right?

Comment: yes, read about int.TryParse here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx I have modified the answer to print the first three numbers in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace this:

```
var values = input.Split(',');
```

to this:

```
var values = input.Split(',').Select(a => int.Parse(a)).OrderBy(a => a).Take(3);
```

It'll give you three smallest numbers.